# How to delete and Recover drive space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, data-recovery

I have looked and don't know where to find how to do this.

First, I think I found why I can't dual boot, With that said I don't want to have to reinstall my Work Win98 system I just want to delete the 2 non working Ubuntu installs. The first one, It looked like everything went well. But no dual boot. SO I removed all my other drives, Tried again. This creating a new install with the Idea that I would just mount and recover the other unused install. However both have failed and I would like to remove the 2 Partitions and 2 swap, delete them and recover the Drive space back to 98.

Anyone have any Ideas? Thank you. I know what I would need to do if I was going to install the 98 fresh. However It is installed all Patches and working well. I would hate to loose all that just to recover this space.

James

Answer (score 0):

lol @

```
I think I just time traveled back to my childhood.
```

gparted?

http://gparted.org/livecd.php

Create a bootable cd and use it to select and delete the partitions in question - just dont delete the win 98 partition. once deleted you would have to format the unpartitioned space - u can still use gparted or reboot and use your win 98 to format the unpartitioned space

Comment: Well I was not sure and wanted to double check before I tried it inside of Disk Management of Win98. When I tried to do it before I asked the question it said it was from another software, Thought maybe it had to be done like inside of Ubuntu. I am glad to report that I was able to take care of it inside of Win98 using Disk Management. Love this site and the Great people that are around to help. Thank you everyone that is able and willing to help others......... James